# How to show installed music players options in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am doing a project in xamarin.

I exactly needed a popup that shows all the music apps installed in my phone on a button click, so user can select anyone of them and play music independently.

I am able to do this in android with music intent.

This is like I want to play an mp3 file and I tapped on a button. The  iOS system shows all the available music in the sheet and by choosing one of them I can play that mp3 file.

[Music intent ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNfr5.png)

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

First you declare an interface to openApp:

```
public interface IOpenAppService
{
    Task<bool> Launch(string stringUri);
}
```

then, in your customRenderer:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(OpenAppService))]
namespace OpenAppLaunch.iOS
{
    public class OpenAppService : IOpenAppService
    {

        public Task<bool> Launch(string stringUri)
        {
            try
            {
                NSUrl request = new NSUrl(stringUrl);
                bool isOpened = UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(stringUrl);

                if (isOpened == false)
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(stringUrl));

                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cannot open url: {0}, Error: {1}", request.AbsoluteString, ex.Message);
                var alertView = new UIAlertView("Error", ex.Message, null, "OK", null);

                alertView.Show();

                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use it by calling `OpenAppService.Launch("skype://");`

Comment: Thanks man for your suggestion but i already know how to open others app, but i really want to open multiple apps that relates to music like itunes player, spotify, muscaly.